# my logo shows down of my navigation bar html/css

Tags: html, css

here my logo shows down of my navbar, ¿how can i move it to my navbar and resize it?

[wrong position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCB9i.png)

here is my code

Code:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MyNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar right">
                    <li class=""active><a href"#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">discord</a></li>
        </div>
    </nav>

</body>
```

Comment: You are missing 2 closing tags one for </ul> and </div> for class collapse.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't fix the logo problem, anyway that would fix future problems thank you very much

Comment: I dont see any problem with html markup. Can you make example so that I can look into it.

Comment: What do you mean with a example? here is my full code if it is what you need https://pastebin.com/vjL05WMk

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have fixed the css and check the below live example.

You have to give fixed width and height to the .navbar-brand class and then just add following css to the img inside as it will cover up the whole .navbar-brand

```
.navbar-brand img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Live example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvXzEg